# How iterate over elements of a sub list

Tags: python-3.x, nested-loops

Hope you can help me with this:

```
previous=[[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 2], [0, 0, 1, 2], [0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 2], [0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 1, 2], [0, 0, 0, 0]]

type(previous)
Out[67]: list

previous[0][-1]
Out[66]: 1

previous[1][-1]
Out[65]: 0

for p in previous:
    print(p)

[0, 0, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 2]
[0, 0, 1, 2]
[0, 0, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 1, 2]
[0, 0, 0, 0]
```

My Question, I need to get the 3 value from each element in the sub list and append it to create another list.

The result should be:

```
[1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0]
```

I tried this but without success:

```
mylist=[]
for p in previous:
    for x in p:
        mylist.append(p[x][-1])
        print(mylist)
```

and:

```
for p in previous:
    for x in p:
        print ([p[x]])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`p` is the sublist, you don't need to loop over it again with `for x in p:` to get the third element (so your code actually raises an `IndexError` when trying to index the sublist `p` if `x` is out of its bound, and will raise an `TypeError` when trying to use `p[x][-1]` to index the number at `p[x]`), still, `p[-1]` is the last element (the fourth in your case), you should either use positive indexing:

```
p[2]  #  the third element
```

Or use negative indexing to get the next-to-last element:

```
p[-2]
```

But if the lists should grow any longer, positive indexing is better since it won't be affected by elements added to the end of the list.

You could also write a list comprehension instead of a `for` loop + `append`:

```
mylist = [p[2] for p in previous]

print(mylist)
```

Output:

```
[1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

In your loop `p` is the sublist. The first time through the loop `p` is

```
[0, 0, 1, 1]
```

Python does zero based indexing (the *first* element is always at index 0). So `p[0]` is the first element. The third element would be `p[2]`.

If you use negative indexes, -1 gives the last element and -2 is the next-to-last or penultimate element.

To modify your solution to work, you can remove the inner loop. You don't need it. You already have the sublist.

```
mylist=[]
for p in previous:
    mylist.append(p[2])

print(mylist)
```